# Asymptotic behavior IEnumerable.Intersect vs HashedSet.IntersectWith

Tags: performance, linq, c#-4.0

I've read a lot of posts and blogs about HashSet and LINQ Set Operations and I get the impression that the linq intersection method internally uses hashed set as the first set, and IEnumerable as the second. So the difference between the two is either O(n + m) for linq intersection, vs. O(n) for hashed set intersection between two hashed sets. Can I get a confirmation of this? The big O for LINQ intersect is not documented in MSDN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's implementation-specific, so in theory it could change - but basically the difference is just that using `HashSet.IntersectWith` you're *starting* with a hash set, so you only need to iterate over one collection.

The "obvious" implementations would give O(M + N) and O(N) complexity for `Intersect` and `IntersectWith` respectively - assuming a decent hash code, of course. I would be immensely surprised to see any other implementation, and I certainly haven't seen any evidence that any version of .NET has shipped with anything other than that.

Arguably if both arguments to `Intersect` were already `HashSet<T>` you *could* optimize this to just iterate over the smaller set and check whether each element is in the larger one. However, this has another problem that the sets may not use the same comparer as each other or as the `Intersect` call.

See my [Edulinq implementation and post](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/archive/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-16-intersect-and-build-fiddling) for some more details, including a note around an inaccuracy in MSDN. MSDN [claims](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb460136.aspx) (at the time of this writing) that:

> When the object returned by this method is enumerated, Intersect enumerates first, collecting all distinct elements of that sequence. It then enumerates second, marking those elements that occur in both sequences. Finally, the marked elements are yielded in the order in which they were collected.

That's not actually true, either in terms of the ordering or the timing:

- It's `second` which is enumerated initially (completely, when `MoveNext()` is first called on the returned sequence)
- The results are yielded as it iterates over `first` - they're streamed, rather than the "mark everything then yield the results" claimed by MSDN

Comment: @Beraliv: Done. (My blog moved a while ago...)